# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Verfiyedusers"

Tags: node.js, mongoose, discord.js, mongoose-schema

Error code:

```
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Verfiyedusers".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
```

Code 1, verfiy.js:

```
const { EmbedBuilder, SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const noblox = require("noblox.js");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  discordId: {
    type: Number,
    required:true,
  },
  robloxId: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  robloxUsername: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  verifiedAt: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  }
});

const Verfiyedusers = mongoose.model('Verfiyedusers', UserSchema);

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('verify')
    .setDescription('Links your Roblox account to your Discord user.')
    .addStringOption(option =>
      option.setName('username')
        .setDescription('Your Roblox username.')
        .setRequired(true)),

  async execute(interaction) {
    try {
    const discordId = interaction.user.id;
    const discordUsername = interaction.user.username;
    const discordAvatar = interaction.user.displayAvatarURL();
    const Robloxusername = interaction.options.getString('username');
    const robloxid = await noblox.getIdFromUsername(Robloxusername);
    const instance = await Verfiyedusers.findOne({ discordId });

    if (instance) {
      const successEmbedV = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setDescription(`${interaction.member.user.username}, your Roblox account has been alradey verified. Do /update to get your roles!`)
      .setColor(0x04900A);
    await interaction.reply({ embeds: [successEmbedV], ephemeral: false });
    return;
    }

    
    if (!robloxid) {
      const RobloxBuilder = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor(0xC27D0E)
        .setTitle('Error - Verification')
        .setAuthor({ name: discordUsername, iconURL: discordAvatar })
        .setDescription(`${interaction.member.user.username}, I could not find a Roblox account with the username \`${Robloxusername}\`. Please make sure you entered the username correctly and try again.`);

      await interaction.reply({ embeds: [RobloxBuilder], ephemeral: false });
      return;
    }

    const VerifyCodeStore = ['art and sleep or add split or use', 'hand and plant or math and color', 'refuse to read or is full and fresh'];

    const VerifyCodelength = Math.floor(Math.random() * VerifyCodeStore.length);
    const VerifyCode = VerifyCodeStore[VerifyCodelength];

    const RobloxBuilderVerfiy = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor(0x0099FF)
      .setTitle('Verification - Code')
      .setAuthor({ name: discordUsername, iconURL: discordAvatar })
      .setDescription(`Please put the following code in your Roblox profile's "About" section: \`${VerifyCode}\` Please confirm when you have updated your Roblox profile's "About" section by responding with \`Done\`.`);
    const message = await interaction.reply({ embeds: [RobloxBuilderVerfiy], ephemeral: false });

    const collectorFilter = m => m.author.id === interaction.user.id && m.content.toLowerCase() === ('done');
    const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageCollector({ filter: collectorFilter, max: 1, time: 120000 });
    
    collector.on('collect', i => {
    })

    collector.on('end', async m => {
      const UserAboutMe =  await noblox.getBlurb(robloxid);
      if ( UserAboutMe ===  VerifyCode) {
        const successEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setAuthor({ name: discordUsername, iconURL: discordAvatar })
        .setDescription(`${interaction.member.user.username}, your Roblox account has been successfully verified. Do /update to get your roles!`)
        .setColor(0x04900A);
       message.edit({ embeds: [successEmbed], ephemeral: false });
    
        
       const userDate = {
        discordId: interaction.user.id,
        robloxId: robloxid,
        robloxUsername: Robloxusername,
        verifiedAt: Date.now()
     };
     await Verfiyedusers.create(userDate);
      return;

      } else {
        const errorEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor(0xC27D0E)
          .setTitle('Error - Verification')
          .setAuthor({ name: discordUsername, iconURL: discordAvatar })
          .setDescription(`${interaction.member.user.username}, the verification code was not found in your Roblox profile's "About" section. Please make sure you entered the code correctly and try again.`);
        message.edit({ embeds: [errorEmbed], ephemeral: false });
        return;
      }
    });

     } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
       const errorEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setDescription(`An error occurred while verifying your Roblox account: ${err.message}`)
        .setColor('#ff2d08');
      interaction.edit({ embeds: [errorEmbed], ephemeral: false });
     }
  },
};
```

Code 2,update.js:

```
const { EmbedBuilder, SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const AdminsSchema = mongoose.model("Admins Binds");
const RankBinds = mongoose.model("RankBinds");
const Verfiyedusers = mongoose.model("Verfiyedusers");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('update')
    .setDescription('Update roles for a user.')
    .addStringOption(Option => 
        Option.setName('mebmer')
        .setDescription('The member that you want to update.')
        .setRequired(true)),

    async execute(interaction) {
        const discordAvatar = interaction.user.displayAvatarURL();
        const discordUsername = interaction.user.username;
        const guild_id = interaction.guild.id 

        const mebmer = interaction.options.getString('mebmer')
        const memberid = mebmer.user.id

    }
}
```

Database:
[Database picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9mCb.png)

Issue:
Ok, so hello guys, I have an issue with the Mongoose model. The issue is that schema hasn't been registered for model "Verified Users," and I really don't know how to fix it. It's saving the data to the database, which is a good thing, but I can't literally "import" it for other code. Even though it's registered and saving the data to the database, like I said, I used the same registered technique for the Admins Binds and for the RankBinds, and I don't have any errors for these 2 models. I'm using Node.js v18.15.0 and Discord JS.

Thx for helping me.